# SetText.exe - Window Title Changer - Not Working

Tags: command-line

Here is the link for SetText, a window title changing script:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021975/changing-title-of-an-application-when-launching-from-command-prompt/39033389#39033389

I tried running it three ways:

1. Command Prompt
2. Batch File
3. My own advanced script that "Finds Window" "Centers Window" "Activates Window Title Bar"

I hear the program event sounds when SetText runs.  The window title does not change.  I really
need this program.  Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I like single purpose tiny apps that do one job really well.  I was going down a Google list of
applet collections when I found this remarkable command line app authored by Ritchie Lawrence.

https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/

It's completely new to me, but **Cmdow** is referenced many times here at Super User and other forums.
**Cmdow** has long list of possible commands.  I tried several, including the window rename command.
It runs with speed and precision.

It reminds me of **NirSoft's NirCmd**.  If you google "command line apps" **NirCmd** will always appear
at the top of the list.  **Cmdow** should be on same page with **NirCmd**.

I'll probably never know why **SetText** failed to work, but I've already renamed a few dozen window
titles with **Cmdow**.

**Cmdow** resolved a huge problem I was having with a script.   I wish Mr. Lawrence had a public email
address or a blog.  I'd like to thank the author for this great command line app.